# How to make this table in LaTeX?

Tags: tables

I'm not an expert in `LaTeX`, and just want to ask. How can we build the following table in `LaTeX`?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Does the linked question help? If not, please show us what you've tried thus far by including a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). From there it would be far easier to advise and help.

Answer (score 8):

Some pointers:

- Since most the cells should be in math mode rather than text mode, use an `array` rather than a `tabular` environment.
- Use text-mode bold italics, when needed, because the letters and numbers should be spaced tightly. Don't use math-mode bold italics in this setting even if that font combination is available.
- For frequently occurring instructions (to set material in text-mode bold italics, say), create shortcut macros as needed.
- Use `\multirow` (from the [multirow](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/multirow) package) to place a cell's contents halfway across two rows.
- Use commands such as `\midrule` (from the [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs) package) to get well-spaced horizontal lines. (If for some reason you don't want to create well-spaced lines, use `\hline` instead...) Try hard *not to use* any vertical lines.
- The example below loads the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` font packages because the screen shot you provided appears to use the Times (New) Roman font family. If you're content using another font, don't load these two packages.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \midrule macro
\usepackage{multirow} % for \multirow macro
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times Roman fonts
\newcommand\xx[1]{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}% shortcut macro
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{*{4}{c}}
\xx{A} & \xx{I1} & \xx{I2} & \xx{I3} \\
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{$\xx{s}$} & -0.056 & -0.117 & 0.000  \\
                          & \pm0.09& \pm0.12& \pm0.00\\[1ex]
\multirow{2}{*}{$\xx{c}$} &    1066 &    1255 &    1099\\
                          & \pm1087 & \pm1189 & \pm1113\\
\midrule
\xx{o} & \xx{2} & \xx{2} & \xx{4}\\
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: .. and the vertical rule `;-)` ?

Comment: @jfbu - I deliberately did *not* produce a vertical rule. :-) If the OP really wants it, he/she should use `\hline` instead of `\midrule`...